# how to assign page template dynamically in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I have a WordPress page created dynamically

```
$my_post = array(
        'post_title' => 'page-for-download',
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'page'

    );
```

now my question is how to assign page template to this page dynamically

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WordPress keeps the page template in a post meta entry(named `_wp_page_template`). Here is what you should do once you create the page:

```
update_post_meta( $new_post_id, '_wp_page_template', 'custom-template.php' );
```

Where `$new_post_id` is the result of `wp_insert_post()`(I assume that this is what you are using to create the new post). Note, that you might want to check to see if you have an actual id(by default `wp_insert_post()` will return false if it fails to create a new post).

You can see that information in the first **NOTE** in the **Parameters** section of the WordPress codex page [Function Reference/wp insert post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)